# I cannot see my web Server from behind my Linksys Router with ISP Static Address

Tags: networking, router, webserver, static-ip

I have a Zentyal Server with an external NIC (For Internet) and Internal NIC (For LAN)

My problem is that I cannot see my Zentyal Server on the Internet.  My 2nd problem is my domain name is not pointing to my server even after I pointed it to my static IP address

Firstly I changed the “A Record” at my domain register (register.com) and set it to the Static IP Address provided by my ISP. (96.58.X.X2)

I have a one Motorola Modem/Router provided by my ISP with the following settings

- Subnet of 255.255.255.252
- The ISP router is in bridge mode
- WAN Port 1 is setting up for static IP address by ISP and the other 4 ports are dynamic with an local IP Address of 192.168.0.1
- My router is a Linksys 1900AC
  Is set with the ISP Static Address 96.58.X.X
  With a subnet of 255.255.255.252
- My Local Network within Linksys Router is:
  192.168.1.1
- My Zentyal Web Server is setup on IP Address 192.168.1.75 with it being static locally within my router
- I used port forwarding of the following:

  - Port 80 as TCP Protocol on IP address 192.168.1.75
  - Port 443 as TCP Protocol on IP address 192.168.1.75
  - This is just for starters, I just wanted to be able to see is on the Internet.

I can get to the Internet on all devices in my network.

But when I use port forwarding I cannot see my web server at all.

I did a test to make sure my web server was working properly, I removed my Linksys Router and placed my web server directly into Motorola ISP Modem/Router on WAN port 1 and it worked just fine after assigning it the static IP Address, default gateway, & subnet given by ISP to my Zentyal Webserver external NIC.

I also have a noip.org account that I was using dynamic IP Address but I was having problems getting my email back to my server, I could send email to other places just fine but getting email back was the problem, this was before I got a Static IP from ISP.

My Zentyal Server supports noip.org for use of dynamic IP Addresses so your web server never loses it's connection to your domain name or the Internet connection etc.

My ISP is Bright House Networks and they state that they do not block inbound nor outbound ports.

You can download Zentyal Server for 100% totally free at www.zentyal.com.

[image: Network Map Photo]

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the Linksys router from the equation. If you remove the Linksys then the Zentyal box will grab your 96.58.x.x2 ip and be viewable to the web. Why do you need the Linksys router there? Zentyal will do everything the Linksys will do in terms of firewall and port forwarding plus more. There really isn't a point in have the linksys in front of the Zentyal.